# How to parse large data with nltk stanford pos tagger in Python

Tags: java, memory

I am working on a program with nltk and stanford pos tagger to parse files with lots of words. Some of my files get executed fine but few gives the following error.

```
OSError: Java command failed : ['C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_60\\bin\\java.exe', '-mx1000m', '-cp',
```

After some research I found that the issue is with less program memory at runtime. The one possible solution is to break one file into two and then process them separately. But, this is not a permanent long term solution for my program. So, now I would want to increase the process memory.

I found this article for allocating memory via [over-commit](http://bryanmarty.com/2012/01/14/forking-jvm/) . It seems that the solution is for linux. I am working on windows 8 and can't find file sysctl.conf  . So anyone can provide me solution of how can I increase memory in my windows environment.

Thanks

Comment: The question isn't how to get more memory, it's what are you doing that exhausts it?

Comment: I am just tagging the data with ntlk pos tagger. It works for other files. Only for few it does not work. If you will do research even on stackoverflow about this error,you will see the problem is with the memory usage. I have tried diving the file into two and then processing it separately and it works.. So what else could be the issue then ?

Comment: The problem, keeping too much in memory, as @caot answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I increased the maximum RAM that java needed to run stanford POS tagger. The command is:

```
nltk.internals.config_java(options='-xmx2G')
```

Restarted the program and it worked

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. This does: StanfordParser(java_options='-Xmx2g')

Answer (score 2):

Try to persist output data to file during data processing if it's possible.