# Give more memory to stanford parser

Tags: memory, stanford-nlp

In the script lexparser.sh, the stanford parser runs with the command

```
java -mx150m -cp "$scriptdir/*:" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser \
 -outputFormat "penn,typedDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz $*
```

However, when parsing a sentence with 59 words in it, I get the error

---

***  WARNING!! OUT OF MEMORY! THERE WAS NOT ENOUGH**  
  **MEMORY TO RUN ALL PARSERS.  EITHER GIVE THE**    
  **JVM MORE MEMORY, SET THE MAXIMUM SENTENCE**      
  **LENGTH WITH -maxLength, OR PERHAPS YOU ARE**     
  **HAPPY TO HAVE THE PARSER FALL BACK TO USING**    
  **A SIMPLER PARSER FOR VERY LONG SENTENCES.      ***

---

According to the FAQ, 350mb should be enough to parse a 100-word sentence. But when I change -mx150m to -mx350m (or -mx1000m), I get the same memory issue. This makes me think that I'm not actually assigning more memory to the program. What can I do to test how much memory I'm assigning, and actually assign more?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to specify the max heap size to Java is:

`java -Xmx1g .....`

Not sure why they have mentioned only `-mx` on the FAQ page instead of `-Xmx`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following line:

```
nltk.internals.config_java(options='-xmx4G')
```

in this thread: [How to parse large data with nltk stanford pos tagger in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398804/how-to-parse-large-data-with-nltk-stanford-pos-tagger-in-python)
But it didn't resolve my OSErrors. The error I got started with

> OSError: Java command failed :
>   ['/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java', '-mx1000m',

leading me to believe that it still has just 1G of memory assigned. If anyone has found a solution to this, I'd be very interested to learn about it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. NLTK ignores it. But this works for me: StanfordParser(java_options='-Xmx4G')